# INSERT problem with ACCESS 2007

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use access 2007
and i have a sql command like below

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO t_person_info(name,surname,bdate,bplace,branch,lang) VALUES('JOE','ADAMS','12/12/2000','London','ENGNR','ENG')";
conn.Open();
command.CommandText = sql;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

But it gives an error **The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.  Try inserting or pasting less data**
So what is the problem,
And how solve it??

Comment: If the database you're appending the data to is a Jet/ACE file (MDB/ACCDB), then you need hash marks around date literals, e.g., `#12/12/2000#`. Your SQL is telling the database to append a string to a date field (which in Jet/ACE is a double, not a string).

Answer (score 1):

Each field has a given length or size. For text fields, it's the number of characters that can be stored. For numeric types, it's the number of bytes that make up the field, which constrains the range of numbers that can be stored in that field.

For example, you are inserting 4 characters in to branch field, yet its length might only be 3.  Check your table and the length/size of each field to be sure they are large enough to accomodate the data you want to store.